# Access SQLAlchemy class field inexplicitly and fix 'object is not subscriptable' error

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm developing my first Flask app using SQLAlchemy models, I've got around 10 classes representing database tables and the classes have fields representing columns.

Now in my `app.py` I'm trying to make a selection of data from the database and get it to have a form of a list of dictionaries (one dictionary representing a row):

`[{'column_name1': 'data1', 'column_name2': 'data2', ...}, {'column_name1': 'data3', 'column_name2': 'data4', ...}, ...]`.

This is what I came up with but it doesn't work:

```py
column_names = table.__table__.columns.keys()  # get columns names
records = table.query.whooshee_search(phrase).all()  # get table records

DATA = []

for record in records:
    row = {}
    for column_name in column_names:
        row[column_name] = record[column_name]
    DATA.append(row)
```

`table` is earlier assigned one of the classes, then `column_names` is a list of strings which are the names of the columns defined in this class. `records` is a list of `table` class objects which represent selected rows (that contain `phrase`). I checked displaying the results in `html` that this works fine and returns what is suppposed to return.

However, I'd like to have them as a dictionary created dynamically (so that I don't have to specify column names for every possible `table` value but make use of `column_names`). The line `row[column_name] = record[column_name]` seems to be the problem - I got the error

`TypeError: 'User' object is not subscriptable`

where `User` is one of the classes (the current value of `table`). `row[column_name] = record.column_name` was my another (silly) approach which of course didn't work either. One last thing to mention is that `{{ record[column_name] }}` was `Jinja2` syntax I used when displaying the results in `html`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Flask-SQLAlchemy` the models defined do not contain a `__getitem__(self, key)` method by default hence you can not do `table["some_key"]`.

One way would be to explicitly define a `__getitem__(self, key)` method in your model definitions. Here is a working example of it.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self):
        self.member = 0

    def __getitem__(self, field):
        return self.__dict__[field]

user = User()
print(user.member) # 0
print(user["member"]) # 0
```

Source:

1. https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/?highlight=model#models
2. [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**getitem**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)

Comment: So this `__getitem__(self, key)` method needs to be defined once per class or separately for every class field?

Comment: Ok, I gave it a try in my project and it works exactly the way I wanted it to work, thanks a million!

Comment: @Theta you need to define this `__getitem__(self, key)` on each model you have. Maybe try doing something like this https://gist.github.com/onlinejudge95/2e00b39b7cc590bf384303ce41606ec1